# Scroll-Position Attribute

Tags: html, css, angularjs, attributes

I've been looking at this angularJS app example (https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/) and noticed an attribute called `scroll-position` that is set to `"scrolled"` in the below div tag

```
<div class="page-top clearfix" scroll-position="scrolled" max- 
height="50" ng-class="{'scrolled': scrolled}">
```

This is a silly question but I can't figure out what this attribute is and where is came from

Full snippet is below

```
<div class="page-top clearfix" scroll-position="scrolled" max-height="50" ng-class="{'scrolled': scrolled}">
  <a href="#/dashboard" class="al-logo clearfix"><span>Blur</span>Admin</a>
  <a href class="collapse-menu-link ion-navicon" ba-sidebar-toggle-menu></a>

  <div class="search">
    <i class="ion-ios-search-strong" ng-click="startSearch()"></i>
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for...">
  </div>

  <div class="user-profile clearfix">
    <div class="al-user-profile" uib-dropdown>
      <a uib-dropdown-toggle class="profile-toggle-link">
        <img ng-src="{{::( 'Nasta' | profilePicture )}}">
      </a>
      <ul  class="top-dropdown-menu profile-dropdown" uib-dropdown-menu>
        <li><i class="dropdown-arr"></i></li>
        <li><a href="#/profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href class="signout"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <msg-center></msg-center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For angular `scroll-position="scrolled"` is a angular attribute directive. The directive have isolated scope which is local to the directive. The directive can be used to perform defined functions. There are also built in directive like `ng-model`, `ng-value`, `ng-class` etc.

For more information:Please visit [Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)